# Getting a pandas DataFrame from a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pickle

I have a python 3 script that calls a sub process.

Below is line of code I use in my script:

Note: Path is my python exe file (the sub process is ran in 2.7 where as the main script is in python 3. The rest are some parameters passed to the sub process.

```
Proc = subprocess.check_output([path,'ListProcessing_V8.py',Table_Names,features,output_file], shell=True)
```

In the script 'LP.py' is a main function. That main function returns a pandas data frame (lets call is Data).

My question is if there is a way to get retrieve Data from 'LP.py' once the sub process is completed.

I've looked into using subprocess.check_output() but the only thing returned were some of the print statements used in 'LP.py', not an actual data frame. Pickle was another idea but I was getting byte errors.

I know I can just output the data frame to some file then read it from the parent file, however I would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What did you use for pickle? Did you try `df.to_pickle(‘file_name’)` or did you open the pickle file yourself using `pickle` module?

Comment: i used df.to_pickle() in the subprocess script. When I made the attempt with pickle, i used subprocess.Popen(..,shell=True,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) instead of whats written in the op.

Then retrieved the pickled df with pd.read_pickle(stdout) in the main scirpt

Comment: By byte error you mean you got Unicode error?

Comment: Error codes:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek',
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes

Comment: Shouldn’t you save the pickle to a file and then read it back from file? Thus `pd.read_pickle(‘file_name’)`?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pickle so not quite sure about that. But i do believe stdout handles that.

Comment: Maybe you can also stdout as csv, if the table is not that big.